# What does "2- place real function" mean?

Tags: statistics, functions, terminology

What does "2-place real function" mean?

This comes up in the context of copulas, [as here](https://books.google.com/books?id=EqbzBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=%222-+place+real+function%22&source=bl&ots=Ev_XtlcLml&sig=qw42Y8ie7v3pm-oPPizBbDSZKsY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=uAJiVdbiGcmS7AbJt4CIDg&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%222-%20place%20real%20function%22&f=false).

Comment: I'd guess, it's a function of two variables. e.g. $f:\Bbb R^2\rightarrow\Bbb R$.

Comment: You're going to have to include more context. It probably means a function mapping two real number inputs to a single real number output, though.

Comment: Is this in a logic text?

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I see this in the copula context.  https://books.google.com/books?id=EqbzBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=%222-+place+real+function%22&source=bl&ots=Ev_XtlcLml&sig=qw42Y8ie7v3pm-oPPizBbDSZKsY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=uAJiVdbiGcmS7AbJt4CIDg&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%222-%20place%20real%20function%22&f=false

Answer (score 2):

> A 2-place real function is a function whose domain is a subset of $(\overline {\mathbb{R}})^2$ and whose range is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

... says the book you are reading.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the 2-place real function is a function which has a two dimensional domain and one dimensional range. In other words, it is a function that takes two inputs and gives one output as result. Please correct me, if I am wrong.

Comment: You understand correctly.